# Grant RDP access to non-admin user

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

Using Windows Server 2012 R2, I want a non-admin user to be able to connect to the server via RDP. I found [this](http://zewaren.net/site/node/91) and added a test non-admin user to the list, however, it still says it mustn't connect due to insufficient privileges. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing step in the tutorial you linked.

You need to allow the RDP connection via the Advanced System settings :

[image]

You can find more info about that here :

http://sysads.co.uk/2013/01/enable-remote-desktop-windows-server-2012/

Comment: Thank you! However, this was already activated, as I can connect with an admin account anytime.

Comment: Okay,did you add the desired users to the **Remote Desktop Users** default group ?

Comment: where to do that?

Comment: Open Server Manager. Click Tool in the right corner of Server Manager and then select Computer Management. In the Computer Management windows, expand Local Users and Groups and select Groups. Double click on Administrators group. You will find the Remote Desktop users group.